# Cascading Dropdowns Using Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm able to get this working except for two things that I just can't figure out:

Problem 1: I need to get both of the following but right now can only achieve one OR the other:

1. Select options need to have value and text
2. The selectedOption captured in the model needs to return the object of the selected option and not just the value of the option

I can affect which one of these works by including or excluding the following from my select markup:

```
...data-bind="optionsValue = 'Id'"...
```

How can I achieve both?

Problem 2:  I need to set the selected option in the dropdown to an object I retrieve from a cookie containing the user's preferred value. My below implementation does not succeed in setting the selected value at all.  What am I missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var userOption = $.cookie("userPref") == null ? undefined : JSON.parse($.cookie("userPref"));

    var model = function(){
        this.options = ko.observableArray();
        this.childOptions = ko.observableArray();
        this.selectedOption = ko.observable(userOption); //this does nothing to set the value

        this.selectedOption(userOption); //this also does nothing

        this.options.subscribe(function(){
            //this.selectedOption() returns an object if optionsValue is excluded from select databinding and returns option value if included
            $.cookie("userPref", JSON.stringify(this.selectedOption());
            this.childOptions(undefined);
            this.childOptions(this.selectedOption() ? this.selectedOption().children : []);
        }.bind(this));
    };

    var viewModel = new model();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myurl",
        success: function(data){
            viewModel.options(data);
        }
    }); 
});

<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'Id', value: selectedOption, optionsCaption: 'Select Option'"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the entire object as the value because an option value must be a simple type: string, int, etc. I suppose you *could* JSON encode the object (so it's a string) and set the value to *that*, but then you'd have to reciprocate on the backend and decode the posted string value back into an object and somehow work with that. However, said object would be disconnected from EF, so you'd have to fetch the object new from the database *anyways* in order to do anything meaningful with it. And, your second problem is the same as your first, you can't use a full object.

The way this is usually done is with ids. You make the option value the object's id. Then, you can set the selected option based on the object's id from the cookie. When you get to the backend, if you need to work with the object, you fetch it by the posted id. Anything else is not really a tenable situation.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I neglected to mention that I did try using the simple type approach by passing the Id value from the stored object to the selectedOption as both a string and integer. No luck. Also, the dropdowns will not be posting back to anything which is why I'm trying to work with the objects themselves which contain all of the child objects I need to get the cascading to work. I don't need/want to make any trips to the database for this functionality.

Comment: Well, form controls are meant to be posted, whether you actually intend to use them for that or not, so the restriction to simple types is required regardless. Perhaps if you edited your question to explain the issues you were having just using ids, someone may be able to help you with that.